# Cut locus of union

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was reading the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.02972.pdf). In Example 3.17 it says that the
$$\mathrm{Cu}(N1\sqcup N_2)= \left\{\frac{1}{2}(\cos s,\sin s, \cos t,\sin t):s,t\in \mathbb{R}\right\},$$
where $N_1 = \{(\cos s,\sin s,0,0):s\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $N_2 = \{(0,0,\cos s, \sin s):s\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Here the cut locus of a subset is defined as:

> $q\in \mathrm{Cu}(N)$ if there exists a distance minimal geodesic joining $N$ to $q$ such that any extension of it beyond $q$ is not a distance minimal geodesic.

Any hint on how they are computing this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can look at Example 4.3.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.14931